# Recursive usage of @Retention annotation , how is it possible?

Tags: java, annotations

In the source code of **@Retention** annotation in java, **@Retention** is used in its definition itself, hows that possible.

Even the **RetentionPolicy** is set at *RUNTIME*, so how could it get executed before its not ready to run.

```
package java.lang.annotation;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Retention {
    /**
     * Returns the retention policy.
     * @return the retention policy
     */
    RetentionPolicy value();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really *recursive*. It is nothing but a **forward** reference to a class respectively interface which is following "later" on. And Java allows using forward references in general. There are various restrictions to that (see the Java Language Specification, for example section [8.3.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e12388)) - but none of these restrictions would apply here.

Beyond that: keep in mind there is no special compilation step here. The compiler simply creates a ordinary class file for the Retention interface. But then: the compiler most likely has *hardcoded* knowledge about this interface. In case *RetentionPolicy.SOURCE* is used, the compiler will exclude the annotation even from the compiled class file. This means that the compiler must be doing some sort of checking (to figure if something is annotated and has *SOURCE* policy enabled).

In other words: the compiler might contain something like

```
if (x instaceof Retention) ...
```

and this code exists within the compiler. The above works fine when compiling some *other* annotation, but it also works when the Retention interface itself is compiled.

But the key message is: there is no recursion, just a forward reference. Something gets used that is defined later on.

Comment: This is also true for `@Target`, which has `@Target(value=ANNOTATION_TYPE)`. +1. I got scared and googled this question, ending up here.

Comment: @MohammadRakibAmin You are very welcome. It is always nice to hear "back" on older content ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need a `Retention` class. Source code first convert to AST. It just need the `Retention`'s qualifield name to get the annotation value. Here is code from OpenJDK

Define the `Retention` by class name:

```
// com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symtab
protected Symtab(Context context) throws CompletionFailure {
    ...
    retentionType = enterClass("java.lang.annotation.Retention");
    ...
}
```

Use the `com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type retentionType` to get the `RetentionPolicy` from AST (line 4 `syms.retentionType.tsym`):

```
// com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types
public RetentionPolicy getRetention(Attribute.Compound a) {
    RetentionPolicy vis = RetentionPolicy.CLASS; // the default
    Attribute.Compound c = a.type.tsym.attribute(syms.retentionType.tsym);
    if (c != null) {
        Attribute value = c.member(names.value);
        if (value != null && value instanceof Attribute.Enum) {
            Name levelName = ((Attribute.Enum)value).value.name;
            if (levelName == names.SOURCE) vis = RetentionPolicy.SOURCE;
            else if (levelName == names.CLASS) vis = RetentionPolicy.CLASS;
            else if (levelName == names.RUNTIME) vis = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
            else ;// /* fail soft */ throw new AssertionError(levelName);
        }
    }
    return vis;
}
```